# The namespace 'x' already contains a definition for 'FixupCollection'

Tags: c#, entities

Everytime I update my entity model (by right-clicking on the .edmx file and selecting 'update model from database') it creates a new model.tt file (which winds up being named model1.tt, etc) which then generates this error.

I then delete model1.tt to remedy it..  However..

How do I keep this from happening? is there a better way to update the model?

Comment: What version of Entity Framework are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've deduced that the answer to this one is that the code generator either isn't smart enough to generate the model twice with different object names, or that it is intended by design.  (meaning, delete your own model to create a new one)

Answer (score 2):

See this article on including multiple .edmx files and see if this helps resolve your issue:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc982041.aspx

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue after upgrading my SP 2007 solution to SP 2010.

What I did to resolve this issue was to remove all references and than rebuilt each project and added reference to other project and everything worked fine.